# Sugessions for simple reporting tool to export to txt

Tags: sql-server-2008, report

I'm looking for a simple reporting tool wherein I can define reports, run them and **export to text file** without change in alignment.  I need to design different report formats and so I dont want to much time in designing the reports.

Some required features are
1.  Group by with headers and footers
2.  Pivot reports are added advantage.

The database is Sqlserver 2008.

Thanks
Raja

Comment: How about `OSQL -S SERVERNAME -E -i thequeryfile.sql -o youroutputfile.txt` or powershell `Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select * from tab " -ServerInstance "Servername" -Database "DbName" > c:\outputFileName.txt"`

Comment: Not sure what you talk.  But if it is a way to transfer my query output to text file, I would need group headers, column headers etc to be saved to the file too...

Comment: Show example report and desired output

Comment: It could be anything. I'm trying to develop a software to process different kinds of report and so I need a report writer to test the software.  I just picked an example from net.  However my requirements are only texts.  http://www.hoaprosolutions.com/images/sample-status-report.jpg

Comment: Maybe try: [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/reporting-services/word-component.aspx) it allows to export to plain text and have support for [.NET/C#](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx)